# Load XYZ point data with UTM coordinates with included zone attribute in x-values?

Tags: qgis, import, utm, xyz

Given a XYZ file with following structure for elevation values (3rd column), x-coordinate (1st column) and y-coordinate (2nd column) for UTM zone 32 N (EPSG:25832):

```
32496000.00 5764000.00  121.26
32496000.00 5764001.00  121.29
32496000.00 5764002.00  121.10
32496000.00 5764003.00  121.03
...
```

How can I get rid of the leading "32" that is meant to be the zone number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EPSG 25832 has no leading "32". 
The EPSG for leading "32" is EPSG:4647.

So you can import the csv as EPSG:4647 and save the result as EPSG:25832

Comment: Nice. More details: https://epsg.io/4647 is the same as https://epsg.io/25832 except for the false easting being 32500000 instead of 500000 - do all UTM zones have equivalent EPSG codes with modified false eastings?

Comment: @Spacedman the leading zone number seems to be used only for the ETRS89 based zones 31N to 33N.

Comment: Leading zone numbers are also common with Gauss-Krüger zones.

Answer (score 0):

One solution can be described as follows:

Find and replace within the XYZ-file with Notepad++ or another text editor as shown in the figure below. This can take some time. Make sure to change the first line by hand afterwards. Save as a separate file. Now you can import your XYZ file into your GIS programm.

[image: Find and replace via Notepad++]